# Migrating SugarCRM to Salesforce

Tags: api, data-loader, migration-tool, data-migration

We have a hosted SugarCRM V 6.3.3 with a MS SQL server backend and wanted to migrate data from it to Salesforce.
No one in the organization is really familiar with inner workings of Sugar.
Is there tool, more like dataloader for Salesforce that I can leverage and get data from Sugar?
Also, are email, tasks and Events (Activties) easy to be imported from Sugar?

I have tried import2 but it doesn't seem to connect since we are hosting Sugar ourselves.

Thanks,
-K

Comment: What edition of Salesforce are you using? 

Do you want to preserve created/modified time & user stamps? If so, then you need to submit a request to Salesforce to allow writing to audit fields on create. Ultimately, you're going to have to get Sugar reports or tables and match them up to Salesforce. Sugar table structure is not directly on-topic here, but maybe someone has experience and can help.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I figured I'll have to contact Salesforce to allow us to write to the audit fields. We are currently using enterprise edition.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ETL tools available in market for ex. dbamp, Cast Iron, boomi etc(https://sites.google.com/site/ezrakenigsberg/)

You can use them to extract data from MS Sql and push it into SFDC.

The main problem you will face around setting relationships, loading history, audit trail, last modified by & modified date kind of system columns and so on.